# OpenLayers - Use it in JS files

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers

I'm currently trying to use OpenLayers to display a basic map with a marker.

The .js and .css library files are imported in my index.php and my code is written in a JavaScript file, imported as well in my index.php.

When I display my index.php in a browser, I get an error : can't find the symbol ol (reference to OpenLayers). And, looking at OpenLayers examples, I'm asking, can OpenLayers be used in external JS files, or does it have to be in a  balise directly inside the html code ? (I am using the last version of OL)

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: we need to see your code

Comment: Please edit your answer, add code and present the problem in a way that can be useful to other people.

Comment: You uses ol before it's imported i guess

Comment: The answer is "YES". The quality of the question currently does not deserve nor allow any further explanation

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard to tell. However yes you can use openlayers in external JS files. Just make sure that you import the openlayers library before importing your external JS files. for example:

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Maps/externalOpenLayerFile.js"></script>
```